# 1953 Loretta Young Decca Records The Littlest Angel

Tags: album

I have this double record that I am getting ready to put on line to sell but was looking at the front sleeve and it says NORKIN  what does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

#### The front sleeve says NORKIN, what does that mean?

Sam Norkin (1917-2011), was an artist who created over 4000 published drawings.

> Sam Norkin was also hired to create many record covers over the years which is the work I most enjoy of his. So if you've always just thought of him as just a Hirschfeld imitator, check these album covers out.

Source: [D R E W • F R I E D M A N: Sam Norkin's Album Cover Art](https://drewfriedman.blogspot.com/2015/08/sam-norkins-album-cover-art.html)

Here is picture of that sleeve from the above link:

> [image]

So he was the artist who created the image used on that record sleeve.